# Deserialization attempted for class oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverter1Byte

Tags: helidon

I am using Helidon 2.5.x and I see some warning messages logged sporadically like below:

`"Deserialization attempted for class oracle.sql.converter.CharacterConverter1Byte, yet there is no global serial filter configured. To automatically configure a filter, please set system property \"helidon.serialFilter.missing.action\" to \"configure\"",`

The message is a warning without a stack trace context - so I am unable to correlate this with any SQL execution to narrow down the problem. A general Github source search indicates it is from [SerializationConfig in Helidon common](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/84123e8caa7f6671efc396526404b2b39d0afbbf/common/common/src/main/java/io/helidon/common/SerializationConfig.java#L187). The error seems to be logged only on certain VMs only when connecting to Oracle DB - however I could be wrong here.

The key mentioned in the message `“helidon.serialFilter.missing.action"` seems to be undocumented. What is the warning trying to tell me, and why should I be setting this additional system property? More importantly, what am I dodging by following the instructions to set the system property?

Is it a recommended solution to set the property?
Where is this documented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the documentation for Helidon 3.x which should pretty much apply to 2.x: https://helidon.io/docs/v3/#/se/security/jep-290  (the main change between 2.x and 3.x is defaults I think).

You can see an example `serial-config.properties` file here https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/blob/3.2.0/examples/integrations/oci/atp-cdi/src/main/resources/META-INF/helidon/serial-config.properties

Comment: okay, oracle.sql.converter.* should take care of all JdbcCharacterConverters implementations. So this also explains why these warning appear only with Oracle as this are essentially from ojdbc jar.

Comment: See also https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/issues/4646. Basically the Oracle JDBC driver deserializes serialized objects from its own artifact for some reason.